# Python not recognizing LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: environment-variables, python3

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH')

0
>>> 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-248:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin
```

For some reason, a package `mujoco_py` that I was trying to import kept complaining with the following message.

```
Exception: 
Missing path to your environment variable. 
Current values LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
Please add following line to .bashrc:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin
```

I had made sure I had added the required path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and on using `os.system()` I found out that the python shell is somehow not able to recognize the variable. What could the issue be?

Comment: Did you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - or just set it in the current shell?

Comment: I exported it and the line is also present in bashrc

Comment: Don't use os.system anyway. It is deprecated since ages and terribly outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the export line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin
```

to the .profile instead of the .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

After you add that link to .bashrc you want to execute the following code.

```
source ./bashrc
```

Then the link is updated.